# How to store multiple checkboxes if they are dynamic in php

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, checkbox, multiple-columns

hi i am trying to store multiple selected values in a new table with last inserted id.

[image]

> my error is array is coming but id_facility value is not coming

here is my form:

```
<ul id="hostel_facility" class="dropdown-menu dropdown-select">
    <?php  $facility = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM os_facilities  ORDER BY id_facility ASC");
        while ($facilityresult = $facility->fetch_assoc()) { ?>
        <li><a><input type="checkbox" name="hostel_facility[]" value="<?php  echo$facilityresult['id_facility']; ?>" /><?php echo $facilityresult['facility_name']; ?></a></li>
    <?php } ?>
</ul>
```

i want to store in new table columns are id_hostel,id_facility

Comment: i check your code its working. i check the `inspect` element name should br `hostel_facility[]` the values also `1` to `n`. what is your pblm?

Comment: what you have make mistake??

Comment: mistake is in controller i assign `parse` variable and calling with `$_post`

Comment: okay happy coding

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My form:

```
<ul id="hostel_facility" class="dropdown-menu dropdown-select">
    <?php  $facility = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM os_facilities  ORDER BY id_facility ASC");
        while ($facilityresult = $facility->fetch_assoc()) { ?>
        <li><a><input type="checkbox" name="hostel_facility[]" value="<?php  echo $facilityresult['id_facility']; ?>" /><?php echo $facilityresult['facility_name']; ?></a></li>
    <?php } ?>
</ul>
```

Here is my controller page after storing the job:

```
$hostelId=$conn->insert_id;
if($addHostel)
{
foreach($hostelData['hostel_facility'] as $key=>$facility)
{
    $conn->query("INSERT INTO os_hostel_facility (id_hostel,id_facility) values ('".$hostelId."','".$facility."')");
}
```